Drive bootable in boot device menu, but not booting when turning on computer normally
I have an HP ProBook 450 G2 thats headless, I connect it to a monitor and use it normally, a problem that's been bugging me ever since I installed Debian Bullseye on it is that I can't boot it normally, I have to hit F9 (Boot Device menu) before being able to actually boot into GRUB and then Debian. It is bootable, I can select it in F9 to actually boot into Debian, but it won't boot when I turn the computer on normally.

Your boot order is wrong: you need to set it in BIOS/UEFI

its fine, the boot order contains my hard drive under cd-rom and usb, it isn't removed
